# How to manage third party files in replicable EC2 instance?

Tags: php, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have a file from a library with size > 50MB so I cannot deploy it with Git in my instances. I include this file in some of my PHP scripts, so what should I do in order to leave my instance replicable and include this file in my scripts?

I can store it in a S3 bucket but im not sure if that's a good practice (including external files).

Comment: Is the question about deployment or where to store the file?

Comment: Where to store to better deploy

Comment: You include a 50Mb file in your php scripts? Seriously?

Comment: Its a BIN file needed for translate some data

Comment: Does the BIN change?  If not why not just leave it stored on the AMI itself?  Otherwise you could just grab it from S3, if it changes from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files that are needed but not practical to keep in a repository are perfect for S3. I typically create a [companyname]-ops or [companyname]-assets S3 bucket with narrow access- such as a read-only IAM role for standard machines.

Part of the deployment process is to push (or pull) your code, and to pull assets from S3.

Obviously this can be done a million ways. I tend to think of code repos, databases, and s3 as tools that have their own uses for deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the files on S3 is one option that I have seen quite often. 
Alternatively you can bake your own AMI with the file already included, so you dont require extra bootstraping. This should also speed up the whole replication process.